# How to stop icon from changing color in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I am using the following icon from fontawesome inside a Bootstrap Jumbotron:

```
<a href="some-link">
    <i class="fab fa-github-square fa-3x"></i>
</a>
```

This is changing the colour of the logo to blue (Like a Hyperlink). How to retain the original colour of the icon?

Comment: Change the colour of the anchor tag. It will be applied to the icon as well.

Comment: The icon is part of a font and fonts don't have native colors. Just like text, the icon is inheriting its color. Change its color as you would with any other text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the link decoration, use the BS class `text-decoration-none` in your link.

```css
.text-github{
  color: #495057;
}
.text-github:hover{
  color: #24292e;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<a href="some-link" class="text-decoration-none">
    <i class="fab fa-github-square fa-3x"></i>
</a>

<!-- Example with bootstrap color
But this is in 'a' element where you need to change color -->
<a href="some-link" class="text-decoration-none text-danger">
    <i class="fab fa-github-square fa-3x"></i>
</a>

<!-- Example with custom color
But this is in 'a' element where you need to change color -->
<a href="some-link" class="text-decoration-none text-github">
    <i class="fab fa-github-square fa-3x"></i>
</a>
```

After you can set the color you wish in your `a` element, as there is not really native color in font-awesome.

More info text format: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/text/

More info text color: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/colors/#color

Comment: For some reason `class="text-decoration-none"` is not working but `class="text-decoration-none text-github"` is working

Comment: So your problem is solved? `text-decoration-none` do not set the color, it will just remove all line when hovering. The second class is the one giving the color.

Answer (score 0):

try to give the anchor tag color property. That should work .
and you may have to change a:hover color to so when you hover on it the color will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the color you want is not in Bootstrap

By writing style, this is easily possible

Add a class to `<a>`

```
<a href="some-link" class="logo">
    <i class="fab fa-github-square fa-3x"></i>
</a>

.logo, .logo:hover{
   color:#c9510c;
}
```